# Node JS https server using only PFX

Tags: node.js, ssl, pfx

I've been running a (Java) web service on my Tomcat server with SSL secured by a PFX wildcard certificate from my employer.

Now I'm trying to port the service to Node Js

In order to run the Node JS server over SSL, I see a lot of guides using this format:

```
var options = {
 key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'),
 cert: fs.readFileSync('server-cert.cert')
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

but in my case I only have a server.pfx (p12) file.

Is there any way to implement the server using only the PFX, as we do in Tomcat?  I'm finding it hard to locate any examples of this

Comment: You can extract key and cert from pfx file: https://wiki.cac.washington.edu/display/infra/Extracting+Certificate+and+Private+Key+Files+from+a+.pfx+File

Comment: thanks - I gathered that would be possible, but is it strictly necessary in Node JS?

Comment: In production env NodeJS server is usually pass via reverse proxy (eg. nginx) and proxy server care about all stuff (static files, ssl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
var options = {
      pfx: fs.readFileSync('server.pfx')
    };
```